# How to set prefab children's components on a script from inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, components, children

I am new to Unity!

I have a player prefab with this tree:
[Player tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzqgC.png)
Each item has a BoxCollider2D component

I also have a wall prefab with this script:
[Wall Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmMBH.png)

What I want to do is set the collider of topCol as the Up Collider variable, the collider of downCol as the Down Collider variable and so on...
I can't seem to figure out how to do it in the inspector, because it seems like I can only select the player prefab boxcollider2d component and not the children ones!

I am aware I can retrieve those components via script, I am just wondering if I can do it just via inspector!

Thank you for reading :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Prefabs (unfortunately) don't work this way.

- Because the player prefab gets instantiated, you want your walls to reference the *instantiated* player: not the prefab player!
- Because your walls *are also* instantiated, it means that you can't reference scene objects (as they may not exist at the time the prefab gets instantiated)!

As a result, you can **only** assign these fields at runtime through code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!